# Unable to read CSV file with double quotes in cell value

Tags: csv, ssis, ssis-2008

I'm trying to read a CSV file with this kind of lines :

"A text";"Another text";"A text with ""quotes"""

In my Flat File connection, I filled the Text qualifier as ".
When I click on the Preview button, the lines are shown properly : A text with ""quotes"" (Shouldn't it show only one double quote btw ?)

But as soon as I try to execute the package, an error occurs saying that the column delimiter cannot be found:

[Source du fichier plat [1313]] Erreur*: «*Le séparateur de colonne pour la colonne «*COL3*» est introuvable.

If I remove those double double-quotes within the cell value it works fine.

Is there any way to make SSIS read those cells with double quotes in it ?

For the same data, you can see how 2008 versus 2012 will preview the data. Observe that Col2 either does, or does not escape the double quote (A text with "quotes" vs A text with ""quotes"")

[image]

The result of using the 2008 version is that it will fail with the following error messages

> The column delimiter for column "Col2" was not found.
>
> An error occurred while processing file "c:\ssisdata\so\input\so_36033443.txt" on data row 1.

A reproduction of the problem using Biml follows

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
  <Connections>
    <FlatFileConnection
      FilePath="c:\ssisdata\so\input\so_36033443.txt"
      FileFormat="FFF_36033443"
      Name="FFSRC" />
  </Connections>
  <FileFormats>
    <FlatFileFormat 
      Name="FFF_36033443"
      IsUnicode="false"
      HeaderRowDelimiter=";"
      CodePage="1252"
      TextQualifer="&quot;"
      >
      <Columns>
        <Column Name="Col0" DataType="AnsiString" Length="10" Delimiter=";"  CodePage="1252"/>
        <Column Name="Col1" DataType="AnsiString" Length="20" Delimiter=";"  CodePage="1252"/>
        <Column Name="Col2" DataType="AnsiString" Length="20" Delimiter="CRLF"  CodePage="1252"/>
      </Columns>
    </FlatFileFormat>
  </FileFormats>
  <Packages>
    <Package Name="so_36033443">
      <Tasks>
        <Dataflow Name="DFT Demo Delimiter">
          <Transformations>
            <FlatFileSource 
              ConnectionName="FFSRC" 
              Name="FFSRC so_36033443" />
            <DerivedColumns Name="DER Placeholder" />
          </Transformations>
        </Dataflow>
      </Tasks>
    </Package>
  </Packages>
</Biml>
```

Comment: Columns cannot contain the text qualifier prior to SQL SERVER 2012.

Comment: Thank you @Balde . I'm currently using VS2008 and SQL 2008 R2. Do I have to install SQL Server 2012 only or do I have to change my VS version too ? Thanks again.

Comment: To create packages for SSIS 2012, you should use Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: If you create an SSIS Package using VS 2010/2012, that package will only run on a SQL Server 2012 installation. As you have SQL Server 2008 installed, that won't work. [Connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/282396/ssis-flat-file-parser-does-not-read-column-delimiters-embedded-in-text-data) covering the behaviour change for SQL Server 2012+

Comment: @billinkc Thank you very much !

Comment: @TabAlleman Thanks too.

Comment: @billinkc I installed VS2010 and SQL Server 2012, tried with this line ("A text";"Another text";"A text with ""quotes""") and it works well, but the "Preview" button does escape the double quote (Seeing "quotes"). But if I replace ""quotes"" by "quotes" in my last column, the same error as 2008 appears on my VS2010/SQL2012 project (Integration Services v11). I don't understand why...?