# SSIS Using SQL Server 2012 in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis, sql-server-2012

I created a SSIS package in Visual Studio 2008.
I have SQL server 2008 R2.

But I have a problem while trying to read CSVs with Text qualifier (") in cell content.

It seems that SQL server 2012 allows reading those cells.

Can I still use my package like that?
Do I have to install another version of VS ?

I installed SQL Server 2012 but I'm still unable to read that cell.

Any help would be appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you specified that your CSV uses a `"` as the text qualifier?

Comment: @billinkc yes I did. My problem is fixed in SQL Server 2012 SSIS but I would prefer to keep using VS2008, I don't know if it's even possible. Thanks

Comment: I'm not understanding the problem. 2008 also exposes the ability use a text qualifier.

Comment: @billinkc yes, but if the text within those qualifiers contains a ", the source will fail. So I have to use SQL Server 2012 BI, the version were this bug has been fixed

Comment: Source data `"ABC",123,"D"DE"` Same connection manager definition in 2008 and 2012. One results in ABC, 123, DDE, the other is ABC, 123, D (or it fails validation)?

Comment: @billinkc [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033443/unable-to-read-csv-file-with-double-quotes-in-cell-value)

Comment: @billinkc in my case (2008), "Preview" displays properly the column, but fails at execution.